# How to get the overall average of the data received

Tags: arduino-uno, current, voltage

I have an arduino uno with two sensors. Voltage and current sensors. I need to get the average value of voltage and current each time the data is received. But i don't know how to add up the current and previous values and divide it to how many values that it has received.

Can someone help me, please? I need it for my project

This is the code i have made

```
void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
    int n=5;
    float sum=0;
    float ave=0;
    for(int x=0;x<n;x++){
        float volt=analogRead(A0);
        float voltage = map(volt,0,1023,0,2500);
        voltage/=100;
        Serial.print("Voltage: ");
        Serial.print(voltage,2);
       sum=sum+voltage;
       }
ave=sum/n;
Serial.print("Average: ");
Serial.print(average,2);
delay(3000);
}
```

But this only takes the average of 5 datas. I want to get the average of all data received.

Comment: Cheat: https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/Average

Comment: it's actually communicative: `(1/3 + 2/3 + 3/3) == (1+2+3)/3`

Comment: @Majenko does your library offer cumulative average, running average, exponential average, or any/all of those?

Comment: To the OP, do you want a cumulative average? As mentioned in the comments on DataFiddler's answer, with a very large number of samples the average will change so slowly that it will be hard to detect a change. (e.g. After a million samples have been averaged, if the input value suddenly change to 0, it will take 100,000 new samples, all at 0, for the average value to change by 10%)

Comment: You might want to use an exponential value or other rolling average instead.

Comment: My library offers all sorts of averages and statistical analysis of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
    static unsigned long count=0;
    static float sum=0;
    float ave=0;
    int volt=analogRead(A0);
    float voltage = map(volt,0,1023,0,2500) / 100.0;
    Serial.print("Voltage: ");
    Serial.print(voltage,2);
    sum=sum+voltage;
    count++;
    ave=sum/count;
    Serial.print("  Average: ");
    Serial.println(ave,2);
    delay(3000);
}
```

This runs quite a while. The average is restarted only with a Reset of your arduino.

Alternatively, you might want to learn about a [moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) (aka low pass filter)

Comment: You println an unknown variable `average`.  You declared `ave`. You should also mention that with this method the algorithm can only run some time until float overflows. A saver way would be A(1) = x(1); A(n+1) = A(n) * (n/(n+1)) + x(n+1)/(n+1). "A(n) = avarage in the n-th iteration; x(n) the n-th sensor value."

Comment: `ave` fixed. It will overflow after 400 years of uninterrupted operation, thanks to `delay(3000);`

Comment: This code receives equal value or output for voltage and average of it. Maybe it doesn't count the previous datas it received

Comment: Did you observe the `static` keyword of `sum`? Eventually you add more Serial.println to check sum and count as well for debugging?

Comment: Oh. I got it! Thank you so much. I just put a wrong variable on the serialprint for average. 

Comment: @Peter Paul Kiefer:  `n/(n+1)` will become 1 or overflow as well. That's not a real solution. The problem is not too realistic anyway, as after some time the average will be pretty constant.

Comment: Yes that's correct - it's not a good solution. It would be better to add a fixed number of values say the last 40, 80, or 150 ones to get a moving average. The reason for which I ask you to mention that the variable can overflow, is because the OP could possibly decrease the measurement interval and then the overflow could be a problem. I did not think about my solution so long, so I made the mistake, that the n could overflow too. So yes, my idea is not better than your way of doing it.